# can you track how long a cell has been the same in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am making a filtered list of trade proposals in [this google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fYGWcqhpUzbdMHwc7KDpRuuoov0keznmQ-DwO5AQMqQ/edit?usp=sharing). I would like to remove those that have been put online in the last 5-10 minutes and only show older ones. I would like to avoid advertising a trade that has been arranged during a private arrangement.

The sheet now pulls a table from a website with IMPORTHTML every 5 minutes. i use an app script to increment a value that changes the IMPORTHTML function slightly in such a way that it forces an update. With a FILTER function on a different sheet i remove all those trades that are not of interest.

How would i be able to check if the contents of the cells imported by the IMPORTHTML have stayed the same during the update?

I don't know what kind of options i may have. I am limited to what is free to use and doesn't need my pc to be connected.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. How are you making that IMPORTHTML updates every 5 minutes? Are you looking to do this using only built-in functions? If you are looking for help with Google Apps Script please be more specific, usually what work better for this is to show what had been tried and including a brief description of the search efforts to find a another in this that might help.

Comment: A potential architecture for your problem is to create a static copy of your importhtml sheet, and then compare the static and the dynamic versions of it to check for changes (and then filter the changes). Doesn't feel like it is rocket science.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is to create an incremental archive of trades in a new 'trades archive' sheet, like this:

```
/**
* Run this function through an installable trigger every 10 minutes.
*
* @param {Object} e The event object (unused.)
*/
function timeTrigger(e) {
  refreshImportHtml_();
  archiveData_();
}


/**
* Increments a counter to force importhtml() to update.
*/
function refreshImportHtml_() {
  const cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('trades!M3');
  cell.setValue((Number(cell.getValue()) || 0) + 1);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}


/**
* Appends rows from 'trades!A2:F' to 'trades archive' provided that
* an identical row does not already appear there.
* Each row is prefixed with a timestamp.
*/
function archiveData_() {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 4 September 2022
  //  - see https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/166441/269219
  const timestamp = new Date();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const source = { range: ss.getRange('trades!A2:F') };
  const target = { sheetName: 'trades archive' };
  target.sheet = ss.getSheetByName(target.sheetName);
  if (!target.sheet) {
    target.sheet = ss.insertSheet(target.sheetName).appendRow(['Timestamp', 'Data']);
    target.sheet.setFrozenRows(1);
  }
  target.range = target.sheet.getRange(source.range.getA1Notation()).offset(0, 1);
  target.keys = target.range.getValues().map(row => row.join(''));
  source.range.getValues().forEach(row => {
    const sourceKey = row.join('');
    if (sourceKey && !target.keys.includes(sourceKey)) {
      target.sheet.appendRow([timestamp].concat(row));
    }
  });
}
```

The new sheet will contain an ever increasing timestamped list of all trades that have been published.

Then **Insert > Sheet**, name the new sheet 'trades new', and put this formula in cell `A2`:

```
=filter( 
  trades!A2:J, 
  len(trades!A2:A), 
  match( 
    transpose(query(transpose(trades!A2:F), "", 9^9)), 
    transpose(query(transpose('trades archive'!B2:G), "", 9^9)), 
    0 
  ) 
)
```

The formula will show rows in 'trades' but only if they also appear in 'trades archive'. In other words, it leaves out rows that are more recent than the ones that have already been archived.

Finally, modify the formula in `'Filtered list'!A2` like this:

```
=filter('trades new'!A2:F, 'trades new'!I2:I = 0)
```

Note that this solution will "reset" every ten minutes, starting the buffer time from *zero* each time. To get a buffer time of minimum five minutes, like you requested, use this formula:

```
=filter( 
  'trades archive'!B2:G, 
  isnumber('trades archive'!A2:A), 
  'trades archive'!A2:A <= now() - 5 / 60 / 24, 
  match( 
    transpose(query(transpose('trades archive'!B2:G), "", 9^9)), 
    transpose(query(transpose(trades!A2:F), "", 9^9)), 
    0 
  ) 
)
```

This formula works the other way around and will show rows in 'trades archive' but only if they also appear in 'trades', and only if they are more than five minutes old. The drawback is that you will need to enter array formulas to get the additional calculated columns you want to display.